# How can I access column in model?

Tags: python, django

How can I access income in NewUser model?
I wanna filter Car model's data by user's income data.My ideal system is car name is shown in car.html if NewUser's income = Car income.
I wrote in models.py

```
class NewUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    income = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, default=None)

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
    income = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, default=None)
```

in views.py

```
from app.models import Car
from django.shortcuts import render

def car(request):
    car_data = Car.objects.all().filter(income=request.user.income)
    return render(request, 'car.html', {'car_data': car_data})
```

When I access car method,AttributeError at /app/car/
'User' object has no attribute 'income' error happens.I really cannot understand why such a error happens.I inherit User model in NewUser,so I think I can access income in request.user.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: Put a `pdb` break-point just before filtering out `Car` models. And paste the content of `request.user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because the User table doesn't have an income column. It is the NewUser model which has it. 
Since there is a OneToOneField between NewUser and User, all you need to do:

```
car_data = Car.objects.all().filter(income=request.user.newuser.income)
```

Also, you state that you inherit User model in NewUser, but that is not true, NewUser inherits models.Model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I wrote your codes, but I got error,RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /app/car/
User has no newuser. So,how should I define  newuser?

Comment: What you should do, in my opinion, is create a NewUser for each User that you have. You are having that error because your User has NOT a NewUser.

In the following link its explained how to do so using django signals: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html